# Arabic phrases in Flex 4.6 are flipped

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, arabic, flex4.6

I have a flex application (version 4.6) that needs to support arabic localization.
The application already handles UTF-8 characters correctly as it is already available in French.
But for some reasons the arabic texts are not correctly displayed and are flipped, i.e. labels are displaying "ghi def abc" instead of "abc def ghi".

The button's text is fetched from an object filled by a Java server that reads a file encoded in UTF-8. In eclipse I checked the content of that object and the words are correctly displayed ("Expressions" view from eclipse).

```
<mx:Button id="button1"
           label="{Messages.currentLanguage['button1']}"
           click="button1_clicked ()"/>
```

in the button1_clicked () function I have added a little piece of coding to check if it could come from the Messages object:

```
private function importFile_clicked ():void
{
    var temp:String = "قائمة مستخدمي المشروع";
    //var temp:String = "toto and titi";      // toto and titi is correctly displayed
    importFile.label = temp;
}
```

But it did not work... The button still displays:

> المشروع مستخدمي قائمة

instead of:

> قائمة مستخدمي المشروع

Note that I also tried to change layoutDirection and direction to "rtl" (both in the mx:button declaration and in the button1_clicked function) but it did not change anything...

I also tried to add special chars at the beginning and end of the string, but with no success: '\u202A', '\u202B', '\u202C', '\u202D', '\u202E', '\u202F'.

I'm really confused...

Comment: Try setting the direction on container of the button, not the button itself. Also, you might (not sure) need to use the "Spark" button/container instead of "MX" (eg: `<s:Button>` instead of `<mx:Button>`. Not sure about the spark/mx thing though. Check the [Adobe documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS19f279b149e7481c49026d1312ea0d08723-8000.html).

Comment: Bingo! If I use Spark instead of "MX" is works even without modifying the direction. However I really need to keep using "MX" or at least makes spark buttons/tabs/grids/etc... look like the "mx" ones. Is it possible to change the look and feel of the spark items? FYI: I am using (and would like to keep) the Halo theme.

Comment: Looks like I answered your comment a little bit too early! I had a closer look at your link and found the solution. Or at least I guess so. I will try it this afternoon. Could you write an answer to my question with your comment from above, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text direction is implemented only on the `Spark` component set according to the Flex documentation about [text direction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS19f279b149e7481c49026d1312ea0d08723-8000.html):

> Support for setting the direction on text controls is built into text controls in the Spark component set because those text controls are based on FTE (Flash Text Engine). Text-based controls that are based on the TextField control do not support mirroring or bidirectional text.

In order to make `MX` controls accept text direction, you should use `Flash Text Engine` for them too by adjusting the compiler([ref](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS19f279b149e7481c4c6270d212ea104536c-7fff.html)):

> To ensure that MX controls use FTE in Flash Builder, select the "Use Flash Text Engine in MX Components" option. On the command line, you can apply the MXFTEText.css theme file:
>
> `mxmlc -theme+=themes/MXFTEText.css MyApp.mxml`
>
> Selecting this option causes most internal dependencies on `UITextField` to be replaced with `UIFTETextField`, which supports FTE. The MX TextInput, TextArea, and RichText text classes do not include this support. You should replace these controls with the equivalent Spark text-based controls.

Comment: FYI, with an ANT build system and if you wish to keep using the Halo L&F, you will have to add:

<compiler.theme append="true" file="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/themes/Halo/halo.swc"/>
            <theme dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/projects/spark" append="true">
                <include name="MXFTEText.css" /> 
            </theme>